siesta: Why is the current 0 for V < 0.8?
I met same problem in this questionsiesta: current-voltage threshold value is not consistent with the band gap value
After I finished this tutorial https://github.com/zerothi/ts-tbt-sisl-tutorial/tree/main/TS_02, I got the following IV curve of graphene.

And there is a question at the end of the tutorial.
Why is the current 0 for V < 0.8?

Hint:see https://github.com/zerothi/ts-tbt-sisl-tutorial/tree/main/TB_01
After checking https://github.com/zerothi/ts-tbt-sisl-tutorial/tree/main/TB_01
I think it may relate with band gap of graphene. Therefore, I calculated the band structure of graphene used in the tutorial. And Here it is:

The band gap here is 0.078eV, but I can still not figure out why is the current 0 for V<0.8?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!
